# What's wrong with this PHP Regex code?

Tags: php, regex

The x modifier code in this tutorial [Php regex tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#8) gives me the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ' ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\validation\test.php on line 16
Pattern not found
```

What's wrong with it?

```
<?php
// create a string
$string = 'sex'."\n".'at'."\n".'noon'."\n".'taxes'."\n";

// create our regex using comments and store the regex
// in a variable to be used with preg_match
$regex ="
/     # opening double quote
^     # caret means beginning of the string
noon  # the pattern to match
/imx
";

// look for a match
if(preg_match($regex, $string))
        {
        echo 'Pattern Found';
        }
else
        {
        echo 'Pattern not found';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra newline in the modifiers because the terminating quote is on a new line after `imx`, that is why you are seeing unknown modifier `' '`

Try changing it to this:

```
$regex ="
/     # opening double quote
^     # caret means beginning of the string
noon  # the pattern to match
/imx";  // move "; to same line as /imx
```

Comment: echo 'hello <br /> 
'
;
This won't generate any error, the ending quote ' and semicolon ; is on newline

Comment: The error was due to PHP seeing the regex modifiers as `imx\n` with a literal newline on the end.  The newline is not a valid modifier.  It was tricky because PHP wouldn't output a newline in the error message, instead you just saw a space `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP gives you the reason for the error in the warning message: *Unknown modifier `' '`*.

Obviously you are not allowed to have white space in the modifier list after the ending delimiter `/` in your pattern.  You can remove this white space with the `trim()` function:

```
if (preg_match(trim($regex), $string))
// ...
```

Comment: That's no solution; the whitespace shouldn't have been in there in the first place.  @drew010 has the correct answer.